# Multiple charts - Improve performance

Tags: javascript, performance, charts, highcharts

My requirement is to display multiple charts with common x-axis. And have x-axis label enabled only for the last chart shown (as they are common).

In the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1dhLut64/, My code creates four charts at the beginning even if only one chart is selected (You could see `updateCharts` method called four times). How do I create a chart for the first time only if it is visible. i.e. only when I click the chart2 checkbox, chart2 should be created. This way I believe performance can be improved. Thank you.

Update method below:

```
// calls other functions, including updatecharts
setTimeout(chartLoaded, 0); 


// To have xAxis label enabled for the last chart selected.
function updateCharts() {
  console.log("updatecharts called")
  const selected = Highcharts.charts.map(chart => 
  document.querySelector(`#checkbox${chart.options.id}`).checked);

  const checkedCheckboxes = selected.filter(x => x).length; // counts true values in selected
  const lastSelected = selected.lastIndexOf(true); // the last index of true
  Highcharts.charts.forEach(function(chart, i) {
    chart.update({
      chart: {
        height: height / checkedCheckboxes
      },
      xAxis: {
        labels: {
          enabled: i === lastSelected
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example store all of the required chart information in an array:

```
const chartsInfo = [{
  container: 'chart1',
  title: 'NorthAmerica1',
  data: data
}, ...];
```

Create only the first chart at the beginning and on select create the next one if not already exist:

```
  document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input').forEach(function(checkbox, index) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

      const id = e.target.dataset.id,
        checked = e.target.checked,
        node = document.querySelector(`#chart${id}`);

      if (!charts[index]) {
        const newChart = new Chart(
          chartsInfo[index].container,
          index + 1,
          chartsInfo[index].title,
          chartsInfo[index].data
        );
        charts[index] = newChart.create();
      }

      if (checked) {
        node.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        node.style.display = 'none';
      }
      updateCharts();
    });
  });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xuf6293k/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#Chart